# Send Notification To All Hubs in a Namespace in Azure

Tags: azure, notifications, azureportal

I am new on Azure portal. I have created a namespace in Azure portal and added three hubs in Namespace. Each Hub has consumer groups.

Now my questions are

1. How to send a notification to all hubs at once?
2. How to send a notification to consumer group of a Hub in given namespace (There might be more than one namespace)?

I am able to send notification Via using Hubname but here I want to send the notification based on namespace.

Any idea or suggestion would be great.